# Add sub-element to function list in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, php

When I code php, I use Notepad++ with nppFTP on the left side of my screen, and the browser on the right side, to quickly see the changes.

On bigger projects, I can easily surpass 1100 rows of code for a single php file of many. Each php file has just one class with a few functions, but as the code grow, the amount of rows for a function get substantially larger too. This means I am scrolling through my code a lot when I work on different sections at a time because one part of the code may rely on another part of the code.

I found out that I can display the function list, which will show me all the functions in my class and a double-click allows me to instantly jump to the function. This is already great, but given that the functions themselves may easily have 300 lines of code, it is still quite a bit of scrolling once I jump to a function.

I found out that I can simply insert the following code in my script to add a fake function that shows up in the function list:

```
    ?><!--} 
    function ____concept() { } 
    {--><?
```

but this only works if this does not break the code. For example, I have a function that processes form posts, and every section is inside a switch() { ... }

So my function that processes all Post events, separate them based on a switch. This makes the code fast and readable, but inserting a fake function breaks the code unless I place the fake function inside the case block. This is a work around, but it would be so much better if I could somehow put the if's and switches inside the function list.

Is there a way I can add sub items to the function list for php files?

[image]

^the above image shows what the function list looks like if I hack fake functions inside. It works, but it means I have to add support in every file at least once. Would be far greater if it would automatically find a switch function and put its cases in there.

Comment: "the functions themselves may easily have 300 lines of code" why are you writing such large functions? Have you heard of [refactoring](https://realpython.com/python-refactoring/)? :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Of course I am using refactoring. Its just that I want to write clean and organized code (some empty rows between parts) and my classes are part of a large web app. The worst thing is, that all the html is in a separate template file, so it really is all code. Some sections I can get away with putting them in separate functions, but most simply rely too much on variables set previously in the function, and I'm definitely not going to work with global vars just to split a function. My code just gradually grows, thats the issue.